# Non-existent polygon inside polgyon

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, error, tool-validation

I inherited some shapefiles that I've been trying to clean up in QGIS and Grass. The shapefile is a large area covering a watershed, the person who digitized it, did so in small chunks without using the snapping tool, so there were many overlaps and gaps. I cleaned those up with the dissolve tool, and everything seems fine.

This is when we run into the problem. When I validate the shapefile, it comes out as invalid with 4 different errors. They are all "polygon inside polygon" but they show up at the coordinates 0,0 and there's nothing actually there.

Has anyone ever had this error?

---

[Here's a link to a Google Drive folder with the files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B3rOmOiSzV-oVHhWX18yUUhQQjA) I've included the shapefile in question, and the two files created from the validation tool. I also included a PSR file showing my steps.

Basically, I'm trying to find the location of the error, according to the Error layer, and when I zoom into the selection it brings me to the coordinates 0,0, and there's no error there.

Comment: Can you include the data and or the actual errors? Are you trying to visualize them in qgis when the "they show up at the coordinates 0,0 and there's nothing actually there" part happens?

Comment: Kristian I have merged your update into your original question.  It appears that you have asked using one account then created a new one to post more info.  In order to update your original question you will need have your account merged. See [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @Joseph [Sorry, I thought I had shared the folder, here it is now.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B3rOmOiSzV-oVHhWX18yUUhQQjA?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting shapefile! I had trouble cleaning it with standard tools such as **Geometry Checker** and GRASS's **v.clean**. But an alternative method is to:

1. **Convert** your polygons to lines:

   ```
   Vector > Geometry Tools > Polygons to lines
   ```
2. **Convert** the lines back into polygons:

   ```
   Vector > Geometry Tools > Lines to polygons
   ```
3. Use **SAGA's Symmetrical Difference** tool with `Layer A` as result from Step 2; `Layer B` as your original *CootesAoIMar2.shp* layer (you can choose if you want to use the `Split Parts` option).

   ```
   Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Vector polygon tools > Symmetrical difference
   ```
4. Use **SAGA's Symmetrical Difference** tool again with `Layer A` as result from Step 2; `Layer B` as result from Step 3 (again, choose if you want to split parts).
5. The result should match that of your original *CootesAoIMar2.shp* layer with hopefully no errors which you can check again using the **Check validity** tool.

---

Showing the first 3 steps

[image: Showing different layers]

Showing the final valid output:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helped, but I'm still getting some issues. Oddly enough, when I use the geometry validation tool on it, I get a valid output. But at this point I can't edit the geometry or anything like that, as it tells me that the geometry is invalid. I upload the new file (ValidOutputMar8) to my Google Drive.

Comment: @Kristian - Glad it helped somewhat! How are you trying to edit the geometry? Moving nodes, reshaping, making holes etc? When I do those things, it works fine (tested on your newly uploaded shapefile too). I'm using QGIS 2.18.2 for Win7 64-bit.

Comment: I've found moving nodes has been fine. I was trying to split off parts and features

Comment: I managed to get rid of the issue! I had to manually go through all of the vertices and look for digitizing errors and mixed up areas. But, after doing that it's letting me split features and it's not showing the file as an invalid geometry in the topology checker.

Comment: @Kristian - Awesome! Glad you got it working :)